# Use sed to Replace Multiple Lines

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to use sed to replace multiple lines which are found via regex with one substitution.  For example, given the following simplified text file

```
first
second
third
fourth
fifth
sixth
seventh
eighth
```

How would I go about using regex to find the second to fourth lines and replace the whole range with one instance of the word "found" so that the end result is

```
first
found
fifth
sixth
seventh
eighth
```

I'm basically looking to combine the substitution syntax (`sed 's/second/found/'`) with the range syntax (`sed '/second/,/fourth/'`) into something like `sed 's/second/,/fourth/found/'` that actually works.

Comment: Is it only second and fourth you want to replace?

Comment: I'm looking to replace a range, so in the example it would be starting with "second" and ending with "fourth" ... ie: "second", "third", and "fourth" should get replaced with one instance of "found"

Comment: What if `second` is present but not `fourth` or vice-versa? What if there's 2 `second`s before the first `fourth`, etc., etc. - all the usual requirements questions for these sort of range problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/second/,/fourth/cfound' file
```

or for those line numbers:

```
sed '2,4cfound' file
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` suited this job better:

```sh
awk '/^second$/ {p=1} !p; /^fourth$/ {p=0; print "found"}' file

first
found
fifth
sixth
seventh
eighth
```

---

If you really want to use `sed` then use:

```sh
sed '/^second$/,/^fourth$/{/^second$/i\
found
d
}' file
```

Comment: ^1 for the awk answer. The sed answer needs boundaries in the regexps and obviously having to test the same regexp twice isn't ideal.

Comment: Thanks so much Ed. I have corrected anchors in sed command but removing repetition of first pattern is beyond my sed-fu :)

Comment: You're welcome. Right, that's the problem with using a range-expression, you usually end up having to duplicate conditions for anything other than the most trivial cases which is why you may as well always use a flag (which means you need awk instead of sed).

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/second/,/third/{d};x;x;s/fourth/found/' input_file
first
found
fifth
sixth
seventh
eighth
```